# WMI & C# can they play together?

Tags: c#, wmi

I have seen the usefull that WMI  can be.

My question,  is all WMI API enable to use with a .net language like C#, or  is it only  through c++ and Scripting enable? Do you know where Can I find information about.

I could only find a few examples.

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh Lord, no.  WMI is farking painful in C++, System.Management is a very nice wrapper around the COM code you'd have to write in C++.  You don't even have to write the C# code yourself.  Download the [WMI Code Creator Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en), it lets you play with the queries and it automatically generates the C# code to cut-and-paste into your project.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the classes in the [`System.Management`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.management.aspx) namespace.